# cpanel change ownership of files

Tags: cpanel, ownership

I'm in a totally new situation.
I have the access on root on a reseller account.
One of the clients for that reseller has a file, he can't modify. Is a file installed with a plugin in wordpress.
That much I understood. He is not the owner of the file. I have to change the owner of that file.
I have shell acces and cron acces but I was not able to use it to solve the problem. 
The solution I come out till now, that doesn't work is adding a new cron job(copy and paste from a forum)

```
 #!/bin/bash cd /var/cpanel/users for user in * do chown -R $user.$user /home/$user/public_html/* done
```

Doesn't work! First of all there is only one line in the cron filed for code so the code above it goes in one line and it looks like is commented. Second, I have no ideea if the cron works. I put my email address to be notified when a cron job is being executed, and I don't get any email.

The only thing I care is to change the ownership of a file.

Answer (score 1):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community Wiki Answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved!
>
> I used http://winscp.net/eng/index.php
>
> Steps:
>
> 1. WinSCP Login/Session Use you data for Hostname, User name and Password
> 2. At File Protocol choose SCP
> 3. Login/ Click Yes for the key
> 4. Go up a directory by clicking ..
> 5. Go to Home and there navigate to your files
> 6. right click on file and on properties you will find the owner of the
>      file and there you can change it